# repetition of input in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

im making  a grocery list app with tkinter but im having trouble where as telling the computer to reject a repeated grocery. my code so far looks like this

```
def getlis():
   global ind,lastite,ovelim,curite   
   curite=groent.get()      
   for x in range(0,len(shotup)):     
      if curite==shotup[x]:
        mylist.insert(ind,shotup[x]+'\t          $%.2f'%(pritup[x]))     
        lastite=shotup[x]     
        if curite==lastite and ovelim>1:       
           mylist.insert([ind],'error, already inputted')       
           t.sleep(1)       
           mylist.delete(ind)  


        ovelim+=1   
      ind+=1
```

i want the computer to first acept that the item i entered into groent matches up with one of the items in the tuple shotup then print it into a listbox, then recording it into a variable called lastite, the last thing you put on the list, ovelim is just a variable that helps keep track in a way. when ovelim>1 and lastite==curite i want the program to return whats in the second if statement, but all im getting is just a continued recording into my list, ive tried reorganizing, true false and mor ebut nothing seems to work

Comment: There are some strange backtick characters on one of the lines of code, making the code syntactically incorrect.  There are also indentation problems; it's impossible to know how much of the code is inside the `if curite...` block.

Comment: looking at it now i see i made some indenting errors that are in my question and not in my program. this is my first time using stack overflow as a question asker so im sure i made some errors, but how do i edit an ask?

Comment: To edit your question, click on the [edit] link immediately before your question.